# jwplayer seek ignored for audio file on Wowza

Tags: wowza, jwplayer6

The following audio file setup in JwPlayer 6 (on Wowza) starts, presumably by the seek, but does not attempt to seek 40 seconds in.

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
autostart: 'false', 
allowfullscreen: 'true', 
width: '320', 
height: '260', 
image: 'http://whatever.com/thumbnails/none.jpg', 
abouttext: 'l', 
base: 'http://whatever.com/jwplayer6/', 
fallback: 'false', 
primary: 'flash', 
sources: [{ file:     'rtmp://stream.whatever.com/flash/mp3:82610788_hi.mp3' }, { file:     'http://stream.whatever.com/flash/82610788_hi.mp3'}]

});

jwplayer('player').seek(40);
```

Can anyone tell me why that is or how to overcome that?